# TeamViewer and remote access problem

Tags: networking, 12.10, windows, remote-access, teamviewer

I install TeamViewer 8 on my Ubuntu 12.10 (64-bit) laptop.

I can remotely connect to my Windows 7 PC (32-bit), but when I try to connect from my Windows 7 device to my Ubuntu device, it works once perfectly, but if I try it again, it stops working.

How can I fix that?

Situation now:
"FROM -> TO"

Ubuntu -> Windows 7 -> Working

Windows 7 -> Ubuntu -> Not working. Constantly says, "Connecting..."

I can send messages from Windows 7 to Ubuntu, but I can't connect.

I connected from my account on TeamViewer 8 and I have devices added to my account.

Comment: You know that the last version of Teamviewer is 9?

Comment: you know this topic have two years old?

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused by something using port 80 on the Ubuntu host.

You can use the `netstat` command to check whether or not something is using Port 80:

Run this command: `sudo netstat -anltp|grep :80`

You'll get an output similar to this:

```
tcp        0      0 192.168.10.79:47041     91.189.92.205:80        ESTABLISHED 2600/firefox    
tcp        0      0 192.168.10.79:45342     173.194.78.95:80        ESTABLISHED 2600/firefox    
tcp        0      0 192.168.10.79:47047     91.189.92.205:80        ESTABLISHED 2600/firefox    
tcp        0      0 192.168.10.79:40666     66.196.65.174:80        TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 192.168.10.79:50710     198.252.206.16:80       ESTABLISHED 2600/firefox    
tcp        0      0 192.168.10.79:47038     91.189.92.205:80        ESTABLISHED 2600/firefox    
tcp        0      0 192.168.10.79:47043     91.189.92.205:80        ESTABLISHED 2600/firefox    
tcp        0      0 192.168.10.79:54318     173.194.41.95:80        ESTABLISHED 2600/firefox    
tcp       29      0 192.168.10.79:36013     198.252.206.25:80       ESTABLISHED 2600/firefox    
tcp        0      0 192.168.10.79:51487     173.194.41.72:80        ESTABLISHED 2600/firefox    
tcp        0      0 192.168.10.79:36219     198.252.206.25:80       ESTABLISHED 2600/firefox    
tcp        0      0 192.168.10.79:36138     198.252.206.25:80       ESTABLISHED 2600/firefox    
tcp        0      0 192.168.10.79:36112     198.252.206.25:80       ESTABLISHED 2600/firefox    
tcp        0      0 192.168.10.79:34545     74.125.132.95:80        ESTABLISHED 2600/firefox    
tcp        1      0 192.168.10.79:60435     91.189.94.25:80         CLOSE_WAIT  2571/ubuntu-geoip-p
tcp        0      0 192.168.10.79:47039     91.189.92.205:80        ESTABLISHED 2600/firefox    
tcp        0      0 192.168.10.79:47044     91.189.92.205:80        ESTABLISHED 2600/firefox    
tcp        0      0 192.168.10.79:47045     91.189.92.205:80        ESTABLISHED 2600/firefox    
tcp      174      0 192.168.10.79:35592     198.252.206.25:80       ESTABLISHED 2600/firefox
```

What you're looking for is the IP address on the left (for me, 192.168.10.79) to end in :80 rather than :34567 for example.

If you see an application that is using 80 (skype and apache2 are likely culprits), you can kill them by using `killall skype` or similar.

From your question it actually sounds like the TeamViewer connection that you used prior is still "stuck open" somehow, so just do the same to TeamViewer (kill it if it's open, then retry).

Comment: what if I need port 80 on the Ubuntu computer?

Comment: TeamViewer automatically chooses another port. It could be blocked by a firewall.